# Access Report Confusion

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that returns the following fields:

- `AccountNum`
- `AccountDescription`
- `AccountGroupID`
- `AccountGroupDescription`
- `StoreName`

I need a report such that

- the rows are the `AccountNum-AccountDescriptions` grouped by the `AccountGroupDescription` sorted by the `AccountGroupID`
- the Columns are the `StoreNames`

It will be used to compare the Accounts used by each store for a given AccountGroup - the account groups are used by all the stores to standardize reporting.

The following Access crosstab query approaches what I am trying to achieve but not sure how to list the account numbers under each store for each account group instead of counting them.

Thanks!

```
TRANSFORM Count(qryAccountNbrsByStore.[Account#]) AS [CountOfAccount#]
SELECT qryAccountNbrsByStore.[CFS LineItem]
FROM qryAccountNbrsByStore
GROUP BY qryAccountNbrsByStore.[CFS LineItem]
PIVOT qryAccountNbrsByStore.StoreName;
```

EDIT 4/22 2:00pm
Sample Query Result Data

```
StoreName AccountNumber AccountGroup  
StoreName1 H237 1-AccountsPayable  
StoreName1 H240 1-AccountsPayable  
StoreName1 H345 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName1 H348 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName1 H351 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName1 H357 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName1 H445 3-AccruedExpenses  
StoreName1 H460 3-AccruedExpensese  
StoreName2 F340 1-AccountsPayable  
StoreName2 F349 1-AccountsPayable  
StoreName2 F456 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName2 F459 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName2 F461 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName2 F564 3-AccruedExpenses  
StoreName3 C123 1-AccountsPayable  
StoreName3 C235 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName3 C238 2-AccountsReceivable  
StoreName3 C333 3-AccruedExpenses
```

Desired Report Output:

The accountNumbers under each AccountGrouping are meant to display under the StoreNames.

1. AccountsPayable

   ```
   StoreName1 StoreName2 StoreName3
         H237       F340       C123  
         H240       F349
   ```
2. AccountsReceivable

   ```
   StoreName1 StoreName2 StoreName3
         H345       F456       C235  
         H348       F459       C238  
         H351       F461  
         H357
   ```
3. AccruedExpenses

   ```
   StoreName1 StoreName2 StoreName3
         H445       F564       C333  
         H460
   ```

…
[image]

Comment: Sample data and an example of the desired result would greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a running count query using a correlated aggregate subquery  which is a complex SQL method that runs correlated functions or aggregates (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `SUM`, `COUNT`) in line to itself. Used here, it generates a new column for running group counts:

```
SELECT q.[AccountGroup], q.[AccountNumber], q.[StoreName],
          (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM qryAccountNbrsByStore sub
           WHERE sub.[AccountNumber] <= q.[AccountNumber]
             AND sub.[AccountGroup] = q.[AccountGroup]
             AND sub.[StoreName] = q.[StoreName]) AS num

FROM qryAccountNbrsByStore q
```

Alternatively, with `DCount` domain function,

```
SELECT q.[AccountGroup], q.[AccountNumber], q.[StoreName],
          DCount("*", "qryAccountNbrsByStore", 
                 "[AccountNumber] <= '" & q.[AccountNumber] & "'
                  AND [AccountGroup] = '" & q.[AccountGroup] & "'
                  AND [StoreName] = '" & q.[StoreName] & "'") AS num

FROM qryAccountNbrsByStore q
```

Then, re-run crosstab on this new above query (or temp table if performance is an issue) and adjust the aggregation to `MIN` or `MAX` since they use string values:

```
TRANSFORM MAX(n.[AccountNumber]) AS [MaxOfAccountNumber]
SELECT n.[AccountGroup], n.[num]
FROM myNewQuery n
GROUP BY n.[AccountGroup], n.[num]
PIVOT n.[StoreName];
```

Also, if you integrate above query in an Access report, be sure to specify `PIVOT` columns which you can further adjust ordering and even omit stores you do not want to show.

```
PIVOT q.StoreName IN ([StoreName1], [StoreName2], [StoreName3])


PIVOT q.StoreName IN ([StoreName3], [StoreName2], [StoreName1])


PIVOT q.StoreName IN ([StoreName1], [StoreName3])
```

Comment: For type mismatch, this query assumes all fields are string: `q.[AccountNumber]`, `q.[AccountGroup]`, `q.[StoreName]` like post shows. As for second, make sure you are spelling Store Names correctly (use `[...]` for any spaces or special characters -no quotes). You should not make up columns but actual store names.

Comment: Can we delete above older comments? Also, please show a snippet of Store Names in underlying data and then show your attempt of `PIVOT IN`. Better to post the error in words and not image.

Comment: Because you have apostrophes in your *AcctNumber*, replace double quotes for single quotes and vice versa (or go back and use correlated subquery with proper use of `PIVOT IN`). Even more, try using a temp table: `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ... INTO myTempTable FROM myQueryWithSub`. Then base report off *myTempTable*. If re-running use `DELETE/INSERT...SELECT` statements before running report.

Comment: So my previous Pivot In attempt was: PIVOT n.StoreName  IN ([Area Chevrolet], [Group Honda], [Area Ford]);   Changed the brackets [] to quotes "" and that did the trick - now have a functioning report.  Ideally I'd prefer not having to "hard-code" my StoreNames into the query as I'd like to be able to add new Stores without editing my queries.  So I swapped the ' with " and that solution now works as well - and no hard-coding required.  Thanks again for all the help here.  Will be doing some reading on SQL in my near future.